# Custom tiles not showing up - SharePoint 2016 on premise

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-server

Have been creating custom tiles on a SharePoint 2016 on premise farm with feature pack 2 and February 2018 CU installed.

This is the code used (see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/custom-tiles-in-sharepoint-server-2016)

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Enable-SPFeature -Identity CustomTiles -Url https://url.of.webapplication.tld -Force
```

So on root page there was a list "Custom Tiles" created. Added the first item and waited 48h, several IISRESET, several times cleaning browser cache, trying new clients never used for SharePoint before. No change.

Ok, hours of investigation and tries like this:

```
$w = Get-SPWebApplication url.of.webapplication.tld 
$w.Properties.CustomTilesListHostUrl = "url.of.webapplication.tld"
$w.Update()
```

Question:
Is my installation broken? How to troubleshoot? My Custom Tiles NewForm.aspx shows a column:

**$Resources:spscore,CustomTilesList_Feature_TileSwitch;**
(see picture below)

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install the wssmui patch from the [Jan 2018 PU](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4011645) (Feb 2018 didn't have one, but March 2018 PU has both an sts-x-none and wssmui patch as well).

Your URL property is also unnecessary (and incorrect, it needs to include the protocol) as this is the same Web Application that your custom tiles list is on.

Lastly, sometimes they don't show up right away due to caching. From your browser (F12) run ClearSuiteLinksCache() on the Console and refresh the page. Sometimes it takes a few times.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So I will try installing March 2018 PU next weekend. Will give feedback/right answer flag if it works! Btw. I forgot to tell I was doing ClearSuiteLinksCache() lots of times, better way should be calling _layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true according to other users. Just for the interest of other people having this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: loginasanotheruser isn't supported with 2013+ due to caches, so I avoid it. ClearSuiteLinksCache() has worked for me in the past. But for the March 2018 PU, make sure you install both the sts-x-none and wssmui.